# Complex validation and submit button enabling in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation

The application has a rather complicated form. File upload, several select2-fields and couple xeditables. These extras do not support ng-dirty very well.  I want to enable 'Submit' button only when all the fields are valid and the file upload passes a server side validation.

Are there some design patterns for managing such a multifaceted validation in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service to calculate if the complicated conditions are met.

Then bind the result, say "condition1", of the complicated calculation, to a ng-switch.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

ng-switch is the more robust because DOM that does not satisfies the condition is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use:

```
ng-if="conditions"
```

Or :

```
ng-show="conditions"
ng-hide="conditions"
```

Tray to write more specyfic where is the problem and that what you want is very easy to find in angularjs documentation.